# Definite article: "the+of+something" mean all things/ people of a group

Tags: definite-article

I read this link about using “the”:

[When is it specific enough for 'the' to be used (e.g. [potential article] + [noun] + [prep.] + [another noun])?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/275541/when-is-it-specific-enough-for-the-to-be-used-e-g-potential-article-nou/275891#275891)

In Eddie Kal’s answer, that said:

(1) I hate **the** residents of that tall building.

==>You are saying you hate **all of them**. You are taking all the people living in that building as a whole, as a collective unity, and you hate that collective unity.

(2) I hate residents of that tall building.

==>You are instead saying you hate **some**, **maybe most,** people living in that building for some reason.

I have another similar situations:

***Situation 1:** I want to make a statement:

(3) **The** nurses in my hospital are nice.

==>Does this mean that I refer to **all** nurses in my hospital?

(4) Nurses in my hospital are nice.

==>Does this mean that I refer to **some, maybe most,** not all nurses?

***Situation 2:** I want to make a statement when standing in a book store:

(5) I love **the** books of this book store.

==> Here I refer to **all** books of that book store.

(6) I love books of this books store

==>Here I refer to **some books, or most** of the books here, not all books.

***Situation 3:** I want to introduce my city to a foreign friend:

(7) **The** stores/ people in my city are nice. Believe me.

==> Here I refer to **all** stores/ people in my city. Right?

(8) Stores/ people in my city are nice. Believe me.

==> Here I refer to **some, or most stores**/ people, not all stores/people in my city. Right?

Is my opinion of each sentence above correct? If not please tell my what is the difference between each pair of sentences.

Comment: It should be, "*... the books **in** this book store*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the use of the definite article is very subtle. It depends on many factors.

Here is one way to think about it: by default, the plural without an article might occur in a sentence that expresses a generalization about a *kind*: "**Nurses** in Canada are very friendly". It portrays Canadian nurses as all basically alike in some way (of course this oversimplifies things; if you want to be exact, use a quantifier like *all*, *most*, or *some*).

However, if making a generalization with respect to a closely associated specific whole or institution, it is often best to use *the*: "**The nurses** in this hospital are nice." (Because a nurse is a role within a hospital.) Likewise, the products in a store: "**The books** in this store are excellent." Or parts of a complex whole: "**The elevators** of this building are slow." Intuitively, this is because the part is expected to be present if you mention the whole—it is not surprising that if you are talking about a hospital, you might bring up its nurses. Whereas it would be odder (without specific context) to say "**The nurses** in Canada are nice." because there is no special association between nurses and countries. (Compare: "I went to the hospital/Canada and **the nurses** were nice." It is normal with "the hospital" but strange with "Canada"—unless it is understood that you were going to Canada for medical treatment, for example.)

Note that liking books *in* a store suggests that you are inside the store when evaluating the books. To talk about the books that a store sells in general, better to phrase it differently: "(What kind of books do you like?) I like **books** from this store" or "I like this store's **books**". There is no definite article then, because you are talking about the kind of books the store sells, and they are not part of the store once they have been sold. However, if you have been discussing the store, the definite article can be used: "(What do you think of this store?) I like **the books** from this store, but I'm not wild about the music."*

** ...I think. This is all extremely difficult to reason about even as a native speaker who has studied definiteness in English.*

Comment: "THE nurses in this hospital are nice." ==>Many native people tell me that "The" is optional in this sentence. Actually, I don't know the reason. It should be a subtle difference, but I don't understand what it is. I think that the version with "the" is more reasonable.

Comment: It may depend on the context.

Comment: I want to give my advice to my friend, I recommend her to try the services of a hospital. I think "the" is fine to use: " The nurses in this hospital is nice, I think you should come there to cure your illness."Could you please give me a context, in which no article is more reasonable to use?

Comment: I think if the focus is on the role of nurse as opposed to some other role, "the" becomes less necessary. "In this hospital, nurses are responsible for medical record-keeping, not doctors." Adding the definite article to "nurses" and "doctors" is not wrong, but it seems to emphasize all the individuals, as opposed to the role (job description).

Comment: "The stores in my town are nice." because stores are a salient feature of towns.==> what if I remove “the”, what is the difference?

Comment: @nschneid Could you help me differentiate between the things are salient to a whole and the ones that aren't, but using more controversial examples? 
If I say "In the last U.S. midterm elections", should I say (the?) voters, (?) candidates, (?) ballots?
I walked into a music store, some people were trying out (?) headphones. How strongly are headphones expected in a music store? Probably, both articles can fit here.

"I opened an excel document and started filling in (?) cells". I think it's just "cells", although they are expected to be in this context. (reasoning: infinite amount?)

Comment: @nschneid
In your post you provided an extremely valuable piece of theory, confirming a lot of my thoughts on articles. Are there any ways to contact you here and ask some more questions, silimar to the ones I asked above? (comments have limited amount of words and I have to be really short while asking here)

Answer (score 1):

I understand these plurals to mean "the things in general, not specific to the store or hospital.

So "Nurses in this hospital are nice", seems similar to "Nurses, when they are in this hospital, are nice".  That is very close in meaning to "The nurses...", and so I judge those sentences to be basically the same in meaning.

However, it is not normal or natural to utter:

> I love books in this bookstore .

This means "when I am in this shop that sells books, I love books (generally all books both the books in the shop and the books not in the shop)" That is rather odd, and I would assume that the article "the" had been omitted in error.

If you want the meaning "some" you should use the word "some"!

> I love some of the books in this bookstore.

The final one is similar to the Nurses example.  I judge the two examples to mean the same.  If you want to say that "some of the people" you must use the word "some".

Comment: If so I CAN NOT say " I love books in this book store", but I CAN say " Books in book store are interesting". Right?

Comment: Well,  "Books in this bookstore are interesting" is similar to the "nurses" example.  I'd accept it, but I would prefer the form with "The books...".  Using "the" means you are saying what you mean, which is good.

Comment: About the example in the link I gave, Similar to "the book" example. I think that, It should be "I hate THE residents of that tall building". The version without "the" is not correct. Right?

Comment: Again, as you have determined *which* residents, you should use "the".

Comment: Why Eddie Kal, the writer of that link said we can use "residents" without "the. Although he/she is also a native speaker.

Comment: Perhaps one of us is wrong!

Comment: As a learner, I don't know which one is correct to use. Should I follow your advice or that person's. I am so confused.

Comment: *I* think you should follow my advice.  You have lots of example sentences, but which one is your **real actual problem that you want to solve now**?  Now, articles "the" and "a" are hard, if your language doesn't use them.  And you see that not every question about their use is agreed, even by native speakers of English.  So you'll just have to make some more mistakes and so improve.

Comment: Ed says "You can say 'residents'."  I say "'the residents' is better".   I'm sure Ed would agree that it isn't wrong to say "the residents". So use that.

Comment: About nurses example, you said “  "Nurses, WHEN they are in this hospital, are nice". I see that you use “when”, this means there are times they are not in the hospital. I am confused here.

Comment: Yes.  Most nurses don't live in hospitals!  They leave the hospital when they finish work and go home.  There are times when they are not in the hospital.  Your sentence seems to mean that the nurses are nice when they are at work in the hospital, (and not nice when they are at home)

Comment: (The) nurses in my hospital are nice. You said they are basically the same in the meaning. I know that the difference is small and subtle, but I still want to know what the subtle difference between them ( with and without “the”). Is that the version without the suggest some or most nurses in my hospital, the version with “the” suggest “all” the nurses in my hospital Could you please tell me your opinion ?

Answer (score 1):

> I hate the residents of that building.

This is what we call a *sweeping statement*. Yes, "the residents" does mean *all* the residents, but it could be a generalisation based on having met just *some* of them.

Your other example of "the stores in my town are nice" is the same. It would be understood to mean that, *in general*, the stores are nice. Saying "*some* are nice" sounds like some are *not* nice, and possibly come over less positive.

Generalisations are very common. Someone saying "I don't like spicy food" could be based on a few bad experiences and doesn't mean they've sampled every spicy dish in existence. Saying "I don't like *some* spicy food" would be taken to mean that you *do* like *some*.

Even though it might be a generalisation, using the definite article means that you are being specific. It wouldn't mean the same if you removed the article. "I hate residents in that building" could mean you don't like the fact that anyone lives there at all - that you'd prefer the building be empty. I'm not going to go through all your examples, but removing the article changes the meaning of all of them in different ways.

Comment: You said :"the stores in my town are nice" is the same. It would be understood to mean that, in general, the stores are nice. " What if I remove "the" like this "stores in my town are nice". What is the difference in the meaning ? The context is that I want to introduce my city to one of my foreign friend.

Comment: It sounds fine to include the definite article in "The stores in my town are nice." because stores are a salient feature of towns. See my answer.

Comment: @LEHANH "Stores in my town are nice" could sound like any store that opens in your town will be nice. Like it's the town that makes them nice. When you take away the definite article it removes the specificity. There might be other inferences too... it could sound like you're saying stores in someone else's town are not nice. Like I said, it affects your examples in different ways.

Comment: "(The) stores in my town are nice".==> The difference is so subtle, so that I can use either. Right? And native speakers also use either too. Right?

Comment: @Astralbee could you please help me with the above question?

Comment: @LEHANH Think of this example... "bananas in chocolate are nice". What does that mean, without a '*the*'? That you could put *any* banana in chocolate and it would be nice. Likewise, 'shops in my town are nice' could mean that any shop in your town would be nice, because your town only has nice shops. That might be true. Or one day all the shops in your town could go out of business because of Amazon and get replaced by some awful ones. Do you see the difference now? "The shops" is specific. It's the shops that exist, the ones you know, the ones there now.

Comment: There are too many shops in my city, I just know that most of them are nice, this means that I am not sure every shop is nice, may be there are 1 or 2  or several shops which I don’t know if it is nice or not. Should I use the sentence with “the” or not for this situation.

Comment: @LEHANH Yes that's what I think.

Comment: Why didn’t you answer my question ? Finally, should I use “the “ or not for my situation above.

Comment: @LEHANH I did answer your question. You asked "should I... or not". And I said yes.

Comment: @Astralbee, It may be due to my wording, so that you couldn't understand what I meant. I meant that should I use "the" or shouldn't I use "the" for this situation?